# Adding Unsigned signals

Tags: vhdl

I have delcare

```
SIGNAL sum,sumsq1,sumsq2,res,m: signed(31 downto 0):=(others => '0');
```

When I perform the following operation inside of a ashycroneous

```
sum   <= TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*try(4),32);
```

I get the right answer = "111111111...111111111111111100" but when I do

```
sum   <= sum + TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*try(4),32);
```

It gets me a number that has nothing to do with the right answer i.e.
answer = "111111100...0000011111111100"

What I am doing wrong? please help

Here is the full code. I commented some sections because I am trying to find the problem and I found that one of them is not getting the right value on the previous mentioned assignment.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
library lpm;
use lpm.lpm_components.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY correlation IS
    PORT (
            CLOCK_50                                        :IN STD_LOGIC;
            SW                                              :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
            LEDG                                            :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
            LEDR                                            :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0));

    function  sqrt  ( d : UNSIGNED ) return UNSIGNED is
        variable a                                      : unsigned(31 downto 0):=d;  --original input.
        variable q                                      : unsigned(15 downto 0):=(others => '0');  --result.
        variable left,right,r                           : unsigned(17 downto 0):=(others => '0');  --input to adder/sub.r-remainder.
        variable i                                      : integer:=0;

    begin
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            right(0):='1';
            right(1):=r(17);
            right(17 downto 2):=q;
            left(1 downto 0):=a(31 downto 30);
            left(17 downto 2):=r(15 downto 0);
            a(31 downto 2):=a(29 downto 0);  --shifting by 2 bit.
            if ( r(17) = '1') then
                r := left + right;
            else
                r := left - right;
            end if;
            q(15 downto 1) := q(14 downto 0);
            q(0) := not r(17);
        end loop; 
        return q;
    end sqrt;
END correlation;


ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF correlation IS
type data_array is array(1 to 10) of integer;

SIGNAL pass,try  : data_array;
SIGNAL s : unsigned(15 downto 0) :=(others => '0');
SIGNAL sum,sumsq1,sumsq2,res,m: signed(31 downto 0):=(others => '0');
SHARED VARIABLE e: unsigned(31 downto 0):=(others => '0');

BEGIN
    pass<=(0,0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3,0);
    try <=(0,0,-1,-2,-4,-7,-4,-5,-3,0); 

    PROCESS (try)
    VARIABLE t,r: INTEGER:=0;
    BEGIN
     IF (CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1') THEN
--      FOR i in 1 to 10 LOOP
--          sum   := TO_SIGNED(TO_INTEGER(pass(i))*TO_INTEGER( try(i)),32);
            sum   <= sum + TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*try(4),32);
--          sumsq1:=sumsq1+TO_SIGNED(TO_INTEGER(pass(i))*TO_INTEGER(pass(i)),32);
--          sumsq2:=sumsq2+TO_SIGNED(TO_INTEGER( try(i))*TO_INTEGER( try(i)),32);
--      END LOOP;
----        t:=TO_INTEGER(sumsq1);
----        r:=TO_INTEGER(sumsq2);
--      e:=TO_UNSIGNED((TO_INTEGER(sumsq1)*TO_INTEGER(sumsq2)),32);
--      
--      s <=sqrt(e);
--
--      res:=TO_SIGNED(TO_INTEGER(sum)/TO_INTEGER(s),32);
--      r:=TO_INTEGER(res);
----     END IF;
----     IF (res>3) THEN LEDG<="11110000"; END IF;
----     IF (res<=3) THEN LEDG<="00001111"; END IF;
     LEDG<=(others => '0');
--   CASE SW(7 downto 0) IS
--     When "00000001" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sum(15 DOWNTO 0)); 
--     When "00000010" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sumsq1(15 DOWNTO 0)); 
--     When "00000100" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sumsq2(15 DOWNTO 0)); 
--     When "00001000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(e(15 DOWNTO 0));
----       When "00010000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(t(15 downto 0)); 
--     When "00010000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(s(15 downto 0)); 
----       When "01000000" => LEDR<=r(15 DOWNTO 0); 
--     When "01000000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(res(15 DOWNTO 0)); 
--      when others => LEDR <=(others => '0');
--    END CASE;
     CASE SW(7 downto 0) IS
        When "00000001" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sum(15 downto 0)); 
        When "00000010" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(2),16)); 
        When "00000100" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(3)*pass(3),16)); 
        When "00001000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(4),16));
        When "00010000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(5),16)); 
        When "00100000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(6),16)); 
        When "01000000" => LEDR<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_signed(try(7),16)); 
        when others => LEDR <=(others => '0');
     END CASE;
--   IF (r>-1/4 AND r<0)    THEN LEDG<="00010000"; END IF;
--   IF (r>-1/2 AND r<-1/4) THEN LEDG<="00110000"; END IF;
--   IF (r>-3/4 AND r<-1/2) THEN LEDG<="01110000"; END IF;
--   IF (r<-3/4)            THEN LEDG<="11110000"; END IF;
--   IF (r>0    AND r<1/4)  THEN LEDG<="00000001"; END IF;
--   IF (r>1/4  AND r<1/2)  THEN LEDG<="00000011"; END IF;
--   IF (r>1/2  AND r<3/4)  THEN LEDG<="00000111"; END IF;
--   IF (r>3/4)             THEN LEDG<="00001111"; END IF;

    END PROCESS;
END Behavior;
```

Comment: "Crazy number" is not a scientific or engineering term. Probably you are getting an overflow. If you provide the values of the operands, more precise answer can be given.

Comment: Indeed, crazy number doesn't help. Please also provide the full statement. If sum in a process? Is it a synchronous process?

Comment: sorry about that I will be more profesional for now on. I hope that the update helps to clarify my question

Comment: Still not enough. What is the previous value of `sum`? What are `pass(4)` and `try(4)`?

Comment: Previous value of sum is ZERO as it is declare I also try to assign it to all zeros but did not change the answer. Pass and TRY are integer vectors hence the type change to signed

Comment: I believe it is not zero. You better show us the full code.

Comment: So how are you observing the values? Is it simulation or actual hardware?

Comment: Your code is missing and `end if` before the `end process`. Library `lpm` etc. aren't needed. Your `sqrt` function can be commented out  (and it's got a dangerous assumption based on length - `d` isn't subtype constrained). (A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would benefit from losing all the commented code. If your results are from simulation the LED and SW stuff isn't needed either.)

Comment: Your process has `try` in the sensitivity list when it should have `CLOCK_50`.

Answer (score 2):

I distilled your example down to an MVCe, and added `sum1` to show the multiplication by itself:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity correlation is
end correlation;

architecture behavior of correlation is
    type data_array is array(1 to 10) of integer;

    signal pass,try  : data_array;
    signal sum: signed(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal sum1: signed(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clock_50:  std_logic := '0';

begin

clock:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clock_50 <= not clock_50;
        if now > 60 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

    pass<=(0,0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3,0);
    try <=(0,0,-1,-2,-4,-7,-4,-5,-3,0); 

    process (clock_50)
    begin
        if (clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1') then
            sum   <= sum + to_signed(pass(4)*try(4),32);
            sum1  <= to_signed(pass(4)*try(4),32);
        end if;
    end process;
end behavior;
```

Note I also changed the process sensitivity list to be sensitive to CLOCK_50, and added a clock process and declaration for CLOCK_50 to make the code a stand alone testbench. Your example was also missing the `end if`.

This gives:
[image: correlation.png]
*(clickable)*

Which shows that the multiplication (`sum1`) works.  It also makes the point that the `sum` is an accumulator where the result of the multiplication is added to sum every clock.

It's likely your crazy number is a snapshot of `sum` taken from your model at some arbitrary point.

You can see on the first clock `sum` has the correct answer too.

One of the reasons for strongly suggesting the use of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), is that the act of creating one can ofttimes point to the problem.

**Added question in comments**

Your additional question should likely have been appended to your present question or asked as a separate question instead of presented as a comment.

> Thanks for the reply I simulated in Modelsim the MCV example provided and it ran no problem. I made a few changes to sweep the array : if (clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1') then FOR i in 1 to 10 LOOP sum <= sum + TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*try(4),32); sum2 <= sum2+ TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*pass(4),32); sum3 <= sum3+ TO_SIGNED(try(i) *try(i),32); END LOOP; end if; Doing this I got 0 as answer. What I am missing?

I created a second architecture to clearly illustrate:

```
architecture different of correlation is
    type data_array is array(1 to 10) of integer;

    signal pass,try  : data_array;
    signal sum, sum2, sum3: signed(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clock_50:  std_logic := '0';

begin

clock:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clock_50 <= not clock_50;
        if now > 60 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

    pass<=(0,0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3,0);
    try <=(0,0,-1,-2,-4,-7,-4,-5,-3,0); 

    process (clock_50)
    begin
     if clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1' then 
         for i in 1 to 10 loop 
             sum  <= sum  + to_signed(pass(4)*try(4),  32);
             sum2 <= sum2 + to_signed(pass(4)*pass(4), 32); 
             sum3 <= sum3 + to_signed(try(i) *try(i),  32); 
         end loop; 
     end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The first thing to note is that you are performing successive sequential signal assignments to the same signal with assignments located in the same process.  Each process has only one set of drivers and process execution occurs until suspended in the same simulation cycle. Suspended by the implied wait statement as a last statement waiting on the sensitivity list.

These assignments occur as successive iterations of a loop and because there's only one projected waveform for any driver for any particular simulation time only the last signal assignment will actually occur. Essentially you're scheduling a signal update for each signal assignment and their projected value is being overwritten by the next until only the last signal assignment is left.

No signal assignment updates a value while any process is still executing or pending in the current simulation cycle.

A signal assignment with a waveform with an element without a delay will cause a delta cycle, and all pending signal assignments for the next queued simulation time will update after the current simulation cycle has completed and before the delta simulation cycle execution begins. Also see this answer - [The VHDL Simulation Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664124/process-statement-in-vhdl/23666714#23666714) for a big picture view of what happens during a simulation cycle.

And if we simulate it, we get expected results:

[image: correlation_loop]
*(clickable)*

`sum` and `sum2` increment as if they weren't in a loop. `sum3` uses the last `try` value which happens to be 0.

Because you have a clock you're expecting these three sets of ten multiplies and adds to occur in one clock cycle. That's not practical or you could simply switch to using variables as assignment targets in the loop statement.

Variable assignment takes effect immediately it's timeless, while signal assignment is schedule for a future event either at the current time (no after, etc.) or some future time (e.g. after 10 ns).

Instead of a loop you could use `i` as a counter, using the last value to produce a signal specifying 10 clocks have occurred. You'd still use `i` as a `try` index.  Assuming CLOCK_50 is the FPGA's 50 MHz clock the idea is that you can't perform 10 multiply and accumulate operations in one clock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I simulated in Modelsim the MCV example provided and it ran no problem. I made a few changes to sweep the array  :

            if (clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1') then
            FOR i in 1 to 10 LOOP
              sum  <= sum + TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*try(4),32);
            sum2 <= sum2+ TO_SIGNED(pass(4)*pass(4),32);
            sum3 <= sum3+ TO_SIGNED(try(i) *try(i),32);
          END LOOP; 
        end if;


Doing this I got 0 as answer. What I am missing?

Comment: Let me see if undertand, The best way to evaluate what is inside the loop is using variables because they can be executing asynchroneous which is not the case with signals. I cannot add code as you do so I cannot show you the changes. What I did is move all the signals but 1 inside the process and make them variables and before leaving the process I assignes to a signal.                                                                      You also mentioned that the sqrt had some probles. should I limit the size of the input/output unsigned. how will you make it work with the code?

Comment: 1. "What I did is move all the signals but 1 inside the process and make them variables and before leaving the process I assignes to a signal."  This is likely impractical,  Can you do 10 mutiple and accumulate operations in 1 clock in silicon? 2.  "...that the sqrt had some probles. should I limit the size of the input/output unsigned.", this hasn't been addressed in this answer and isn't part of your question. What happens if the actual isn't the same length as the formal `d`?

Comment: you are right, I was forgetting that I am programming harward, a counter will be best to use instead of a loop.

Comment: I changed it and I get the right answer every time. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The final code will be as follow

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


ENTITY correlation IS
    PORT (
            CLOCK_50                                        :IN STD_LOGIC);
end correlation;

architecture behavior of correlation is
     type data_array is array(1 to 10) of integer;

     signal pass,try : data_array;
     signal sum      : signed(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
     signal sum2     : unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
     signal sum3     : unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

     pass<=(0,0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3,0);
     try <=(0,0,-1,-2,4,-7,-4,-5,-3,0); 

     PROCESS (clock_50)
         variable i  :integer:=0;
     BEGIN
        if (clock_50'event and clock_50 = '1') then
            IF i<10 THEN
                i:=i+1;      
                sum  <= sum + TO_SIGNED(pass(i)*try(i),32);
                sum2 <= sum2+ TO_UNSIGNED(pass(i)*pass(i),32);
                sum3 <= sum3+ TO_UNSIGNED(try(i) *try(i),32);
             END IF;
         END IF;
     END PROCESS;
END Behavior;
```

This sweeps the array and gives the right answer for SUM, SUM1 and SUM2
Obviously the loop does give the time to adders and multipliers to operate. Replacing it with a counter the operation of this component will be performed in different clock cycles for each value of the array