# VHDL result erased when value is assigned to RAM

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to construct a cipher in VHDL. The `I_0` is input and the `O_0` is output. The omega_in is the starting value of a counter. My input and output are currently giving the right values. But if I erase the comments in the second if else (`s(0) <= I_0` and `s(0) <= s(0) xor I_0`) nothing is assigned my ram at place 0, and therefore `O_0` does not hold the right value.

The problem can be solved by replacing omega in the first if statement by omega_in, but this is not what I want because eventualy the code is going to contain more if statements and omega and omega_in will differ.

My code looks like

```
entity Piston_Crypt is
Port (I_0        :in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      O_0        :out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      omega_in   :in integer;
      unwrapFlag :in std_logic;
      Rs             :in integer;
      CryptEnd   :in integer
);
end Piston_Crypt;

architecture Behavioral of Piston_Crypt is

signal omega : integer;

type ram_type is array(0 to 800) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal s : ram_type;

begin
process(omega_in, Rs, omega)
begin
    s(0) <= X"aa";
    s(1) <= X"80";
    s(2) <= X"9d";
    omega <= omega_in;
    if (omega < Rs) then
        O_0 <= s(0) xor I_0;    -- O.PUSHBYTE(s[omega] xor x)
        if (unwrapFlag = '1') then
            --s(0) <= I_0;
        else
            --s(0) <= s(0) xor I_0;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Can someone explain to me why VHDL does not assign anything to `s(0)` (or erased it) and how I can solve it?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2 Simple signal assignments, 14.7.3.4 Signal updates, 14.7.5.2 Simulation cycle. Signal assignments are scheduled to occur, in this case at the current simulation time (the default delay is after 0 ns). Signal updates occur after all pending processes have suspended (including the one doing the assignment).  The simplest thing you could do would be to make s a variable declared in this process. If you need s to be a signal assign default values, if you can't assign values in a different operation than the one that consumes them.

Comment: See the answer to [hardware programming - process statement in vhdl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664124/process-statement-in-vhdl/23666714#23666714). As you might gather if you search on Stackoverflow the same problem gets mentioned in a plethora of different ways.