# VHDL signed data in std_logic_vector to unsigned data

Tags: casting, vhdl, twos-complement

I have an ADC (LTC1407A-1) on an FPGA board that is populating a 14-bit register with 2's compliment signed data. I want to convert this data to be unsigned:

- Source data range: `-8192 to 8191`
- Target data range: `0 to 16383`

However, whatever I try, I can't seem to get the desired result. My current section of working code for the VHDL register module is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reg10 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;                         --50MHz clock
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;                       --asynchronous reset
           i_load : in  STD_LOGIC;                      --load signal
           i_data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 0); --data signal
           o_data : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) --output data
    );
end reg10;

architecture Behavioral of reg10 is
    signal s_data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
    signal f_data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 downto 0);
    signal t_sign : signed (13 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            s_data <= "0000000000";
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
            t_sign <= SIGNED(i_data);
            f_data <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(t_sign);
            s_data <= "00" & f_data(13 downto 6);
        end if;
    end process;
    o_data <= "000010" & s_data(9 downto 0);
end Behavioral;
```

I have done plenty of searching around and find lots of examples where the conversion can be done, but, I don't understand the correct approach to take. I have tried assigning `i_data` as `signed`, casting between variables internally, and many other recommended solutions, but all to no avail.

```
signal t_sign : signed (13 downto 0);
f_data <= conv_std_logic_vector(i_data, 14);
```

The code buffers a changing input vector, and formats the data into an output vector for a VGA controller to display.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, what IS the desired result? Especially when values in the source are not legal values in the target, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @brian-drummond The desired result is the input is converted from 2's compliment to unsigned, biased at half way.

Comment: Then why not just say the desired result is to add 8192?

Comment: Because I hadn't thought of it like that, but yes, this is correct. The desired result would be to add 8192 to the input. How would I go about this within the above context.

Comment: I'd use the numeric_std library and write something a bit like `my_unsigned <= unsigned(my_signed + 8192);`

Comment: Shouldn't that be a target range of 0 to 16393?

Comment: @user1155120 yes, thanks, fixed :)

Comment: For why there are pipeline delays through t_sign, f_data and s_data see [process statement in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664124/process-statement-in-vhdl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is:

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

Don't do that. Do this:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

The other library already treats std_logic as signed or unsigned. You shouldn't want that.
Then cast from signed to std_logic_vector to unsigned. e.g.:

```
[signal] foo <= unsigned(std_logic_vector(signed(bar)));
```

however, in you case the input is already std_logic, so just cast to unsigned. It should work, unless your input representation is non-standard. (I.e. has an offset). IF it has an offset, do something like:

```
[signal] foo <= unsigned(std_logic_vector(signed(bar)+offset));
```

**N.B. `<=` [signal] assignments are assigned at the next delta (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_delay). So in a process that is evaluated within one delta (i.e. without wait statements), they are not applied until after the process ends. So in you example, even though `f_data` is assigned by the data in `t_sign` the line *after* `t_sign` is assigned, `t_sign` will not change until the end of the process, so its change will not directly effect `f_data`. Instead the process will trigger on the next `clk` and `clk'event and clk = '1'` will assign `f_data` the new processed value `t_sign`. In effect each `<=` will insert a register in your example.**

**edit:**
I myself would probably use a cast to integer.

```
foo <= to_unsigned(to_integer(bar)+offset, foo'length);
```

Comment: p.s. I do a cast via std_logic_vector, which is probably not really required, however, it is clearer readable code. If one would ever implement a range check when casting directly from signed to unsigned, negative numers will cause an error.

Comment: Just a related side question, the data in `i_data` is signed. But I guess my original issue was that the compiler (if that's the right word) didn't know that, and was treating it as unsigned. How to I make it clear to the compiler that `i_data` is signed? I know that's inherent in your answer, but, I'm not 100% clear of where that is. Very useful and informative, thanks! Not enough REP to +1 but cheers!

Comment: You could mark my answer as the selected answer (if you thinks it is the proper answer), because you're the asker. On your side question: the output of the ADC might be "signed" (probably having a biased), the data type `std_logic_vector` is just an array of `std_logic`, neither signed nor unsigned. However if you use `std_logic_arith` some arithmetic can be done on `std_logic_vector`, but clearly not the one you want. It's better to use `numeric_std`, so you can cast the input either to `signed` or `unsigned` for proper arithmetic. When using the `signed` data type, the most significant

Comment: ...bit is automatically used as the sign bit. So when converting `std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)` to signed, it should also be `signed(13 downto 0)` for proper sign placement. So when using `signed(i_data)` it will already be proper 2's complement signed data. One thing I forgot to mention is that `signed(i_data)+8192` actually causes an arithmetic overflow, as for instance `8191+8192=16383` cannot be represented in 13 bits. But for `signed` this will not cause an error: the number will just wrap-around. So no problem is expected.

Comment: The N.B. `the <= takes a clock-cycle to process.` is nonsense. It takes a delta cycle to process. It might be a clock cycle before you observe the result in a clocked process, but that's an entirely different point.

Comment: You're right. I will clarify the answer. By the way. Did you give me a -1 just for that???

Comment: Better. Misleading answers do deserve -1, now removed. Formally "... until the process suspends" which could be at a `Wait` but in this process is indeed when it ends.

Comment: That seems quite harsh to me. I would reserve any total score of <0 only for non-contributing or really bad answers... Possible errors in answers can be discussed in comments and fixed. Or just edit a post to correct it, if you're allowed it, like mfro did when I accidentally wrote `std_numeric`

Comment: Well, it was fixed. And the downvote went away.  Sorry if that still seems harsh but the trouble with that particular misconception is that it's a pernicious one, it popped up again just today in another Q/A and one gets fed up of playing whackamole.

Answer (score 1):

Your i_data has a range of 13 downto 0. As Brian mentioned the conversion can be accomplished by adding 8192.

8192 is "1_0000_0000_0000" as a bit_string representing binary with a length matching i_data.

That means to convert by addition you're only flipping the MSB in addition with a result the length of the longest operand. Because you're also truncating in the s_data assignment you only need 8 flip flops.

For:

```
signal s_data:  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
```

we could assign s_data as:

```
s_data <= (i_data(13) xor '1') & i_data(12 downto 6);
```

where the o_data assignment becomes:

```
o_data <= "00001000" & s_data;
```

Without concern for carry the addition simplifies to a single XOR gate to flip the sign converting two's complement to a binary magnitude expression.

f_data and t_data are not needed as J.H. Bonarius indicates unless two additional pipeline stages are desired.

You could also ask whether registering is needed at all when only introducing one gate delay.

If the register is eliminated:

```
o_data <= "00001000" & (i_data(13) xor '1') & i_data(12 downto 6);
```

and you can also note that at no time are 'bits' i_data(5 downto 0) used.

And because XOR with a constant '1' on one input is inversion:

```
o_data <= "00001000" & not i_data(13) & i_data(12 downto 6);
```

that operation can be logical not.

Note that an arithmetic package is not needed nor are type conversions (cast is inaccurate in VHDL, type conversion is allowed only between closely related types see IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.6 Type conversions).

You could also expect that synthesis would optimize adding 8192 to essentially the same result if the apparently unnecessary pipeline registers are eliminated. In a modification of your original model to add 8192, that would also imply some of those pipeline register 'bits' be optimized away.

Your design model also doesn't use i_load.

Comment: What you explain in your second-to-last paragraph is important. Modern synthesis tools likely optimize-away the adders for `... + 8192`. So it is not necessary to do these optimizations any longer. Just write what you want to do, that makes code more readable and maintainable. If I would read `o_data <= "00001000" & not i_data(13) & i_data(12 downto 6);` I would think "what's happening here", while `o_data <= unsigned(signed(i_data)+8192);` is very clear. And even better would be to replace the `8192` 'magic number' by a constant called `dc_offset` or so..

Comment: Also: most people do not have access to IEEE Std 1076-2008 (you have to have a paid IEEE subscription), so it's better to quote the information. ;)

Comment: The add filters conversion through a programming language precept. A HW guy might use the not value in pin connectivity, would document and still expect the reader to understand VHDL and hardware. A mathematician might require the use type SIGNED on the i_data port. An organization might also require documenting comments and type conversions that can be reviewed. Also see IEEE Std1076 -1987 thru -2002 7.3.5 Type conversions. The information "type conversion is allowed only between closely related types", the LRM reference is the authority and yes, costs. These comments seem poorly focused.

Comment: Thank you user1155120 and @J.H.Bonarius for the info. I'm a total beginner with good Embedded C and electronics knowledge, but, I'm totally new to VHDL. Less than a week's total experience. Cheers!